# How to enable/disable WiFI ACL settings for MAC address filtering

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

How to enable/disable WiFI ACL settings for MAC address filtering.

Version: RouterOS 7.13.4

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you *shouldn't* use MAC ACLs for Wi-Fi (because of how trivial they are to spoof), but in RouterOS with the 'old' wireless package this functionality is available under "Interfaces > Wireless > Access list".

If you want to block all clients except specific allowed entries, make sure the "Default Authenticate" and "Default Forward" parameters are disabled on the Wi-Fi interfaces (both of them).

If you want the opposite (allow everything except blocked), make sure the parameters are enabled.

Comment: This is in the old version, in the new version of RouterOS 7.13.4
it's not anymore.

Comment: In 7.13 you can have either 'wifi' (new) **or** 'wireless' (old) packages installed – if your hardware is compatible with the old package, you can keep using it like before. I don't have an answer for the new 'wifi' package.

Comment: I have WiFi packages installed :(

Comment: Can anyone really help?